# Displaying information from local data in a table

Tags: javascript, c#, html, local-storage

So I have a project to create a webpage that accepts user input on one page and displays it in a table on another page. I know at least some of the local storage is working because I called the 'textvalue' and it always has the user input correct. I can't seem to figure out why I can't get the data to display on the table though.

This is the code that I have to the page that takes the user input and throws it into local storage.

```html
@page
@model RSVPModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RSVP";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>RSVP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type=" text/css" href="style.css" />

    <script>
        function getDetails() {
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            localStorage.setItem("textvalue", name);
            var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
            localStorage.setItem("agevalue", age);
            var arrtime = document.getElementById("arrtime").value;
            localStorage.setItem("timevalue", arrtime);
            var parking = document.getElementById("parking").value;
            localStorage.setItem("parkingvalue", parking);
            return false;
            
            if (!name || !age || !arrtime || !parking) {
                alert("Please fill all fields before proceeding");
                return;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
        <div id=" container">
            <div class=" input">Name: <input id="name" type="text" /></div>
            <div class=" input">Age: <input id="age" type="number" /></div>
            <div class=" input">Arrival Time: <input id="arrtime" type="time" /></div>
            <label for="parking">Request Parking?</label>
            <select name="parking" id="parking"> 
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="yes">yes</option>
                <option value="no">no</option>
            </select>

            <form action="Submitted">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit RSVP" onclick="getDetails();"/>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    
</body>    
</html>
```

After the input page hitting the submit button will take them to a thank you page where they can navigate to the table page via a link on the page or the nav bar at the top of the page. Here is the code for that page.

```html
@page
@model SubmittedModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RSVP Submitted";
}
<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Thank you <span id="result"></span>!</h1>
        <p>It's great that you're coming. The drinks are already in the fridge!</p>
        <p>Click <a href="GuestList">here</a> to see who is coming.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("textvalue");
    </script>
</body>
```

And this is the code I have for the page that tries to take that out of local storage, assign it to a variable, and then display it in the table.

```html
@page
@model PrivacyModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Here is a list of people attending the party";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<body>
    <script>
        var row = 1;

        var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
        submit.addEventListener("click", displayDetails);

        function displayDetails() {
            document.getElementById("guestName").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("textvalue");
            document.getElementById("guestAge").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("agevalue");
            document.getElementById("arrivalTime").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("timevalue");
            document.getElementById("parkingRequest").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("parkingvalue");

            var display = document.getElementById("display");

            var newRow = display.insertRow(row);

            var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);

            cell1.innerHTML = guestName;
            cell2.innerHTML = guestAge;
            cell3.innerHTML = arrivalTime;
            cell4.innerHTML = parkingRequest;

            row++;
        }        
    </script>
    <table id="display">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Arrival Time</th>
            <th>Request Parking</th>
        </tr>
    </table>


</body>
```

I couldn't really find any information on a process like this, so I'm trying to piece together like 3 different tutorials. I might just need some fresh eyes to spot a simple mistake or I could be doing it completely wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code which takes user from first page to the second page?

Comment: So it doesn't take them from input page to table page. There is an inbetween page that displays a thank you for the RSVP. Then they are able to navigate to the page with the table from either a link in the nav bar or a link on the thank you page. I'll post the thank you page in the middle of the post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what happened on you code. If the following code is working, maybe you can modify it.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <span>Test</span><input type="text" id="input_test" size="14" value="new">
    </div>
    <div>
            <button type="button" id="save">Save</button>                   
    </div>
    <div>
            <button type="button" id="load">Load</button>                   
    </div>
    <table id="table_test">
        <tr>
            <th>test</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

<script>
    let save = document.getElementById('save');
    save.addEventListener("click", saveDetails);
    function saveDetails() {
        localStorage.setItem("Test",  document.getElementById('input_test').value); 
    }

    let load = document.getElementById('load');
    load.addEventListener("click", loadDetails);
    function loadDetails() {
        let t = document.getElementById('table_test');
        let r = t.insertRow(1);
        let c = r.insertCell(0);
        c.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Test");
        
    }   
</script>
```